# JSF Richfaces upgrade

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm fairly new to JSF and Richfaces.

I'm looking to upgrade our system from JSF 1.1.2 to the latest 2.0. Also looking at upgrading our Richfaces 3.0 to 3.3

Under the lib folder for old projects we currently have the following:

```
ajax4jsf-1.1.1.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.0.jar
commons-collections-3.3.1.0.jar
commons-digester-1.6.0.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.0.jar
jsf-api-1.1.2.0.jar
jsf-facelets-1.1.12.0.jar
jsf-impl-1.1.2.0.jar
jstl-1.1.2.0.jar
richfaces-3.0.1.1.jar
```

This is what I have added:

```
richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final (Added)
richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final (Added)
richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final (Added)
```

So what I'm looking for is info on what Jars I can remove and what Jars I'm missing that need to be added.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, before talking about the libs... What's your goal using jsf 2.0 and rf 3.3? I am asking because rf 3.3 does not really make use of jsf 2.0. As the jsf 2.0 roadmap for richfaces says

> The goal of JSF 2.0 support in the 3.3.3 release is to run your existing RichFaces 3.3.X applications in a JSF 2.0/EE6 environment with little or no changes.

See this link: [jsf 2.0 roadmap for richfaces](http://relation.to/Bloggers/JSF20RoadmapForRichFaces)

OK, back to your libs... I don't remember them by heart, but at least you should change jsf-api and jsf-impl to 2.x versions and drop the old stuff. I would have a look at a rf 3.3 demo project, what is contained there.

Comment: Reason we are using Richfaces 3.3 is to keep it up to date and prevent a long gap between latest release and what are developing in. There are a number of features we will be adding to our application also, we want to be able use the latest options available in Richfaces to allow slicker interfaces. I'll look into your demo project suggestion.

Comment: One last comment, should JARs I'm downloading be checked for safe code? I.e. does Oracle provide some tool I can use to ensure the JARs are legitimate?

Comment: I usually download libraries I need directly from the vendor - and trust them. (Maybe the scary among us, wouldn't. : -) So in your example I would download richfaces directly from jboss and jsf from oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use RichFaces Maven archetype and create a project with everything you need.